# Switch regulator driven by a super capacitor

Tags: switching-regulator, supercapacitor, buck-boost

I am trying to design a Power Management circuit with some quite tricky (for me at least) requirements. Basically I have a quite high 30-40V (varies) input voltage, with a very low current limit (6mA max in worst case, but it some cases there are more). The goal is to make a circuit which can periodically drive the WiFi of an ESP32 (needs 300mA @ 3.3V) in order to deliver data to a server. (For those of you that have not guessed it, this is an Mbus slave device and the master is guaranteed to support 4UL or more).

My idea is to have the ESP32 run with the radio off when in idle mode. This should be fully possible with a standard Buck converter supply. However, it need a time limited power "boost" for 1-2 seconds when ever I need to turn on the Wifi and send data.

I've designed a switched current limited super capacitor charging circuit. This should insure the capacitor is charged with a constant current, while monitoring the bus voltage to insure we are not overloading it (reducing current further if we do). This is adjustable to any output voltage I would like on the supercap.

The problem is finding a suitable switching regulator that takes the voltage from the Super Capacitor and converts it to a 3.9V @ >300mA (as I need this to supplement the main supply through a diode so it does not interfere with it's feedback). I thought finding something suitable would be easy, but I have not been able to do so. The main problem is that the super capacitor can have a voltage higher (up to 5V) than the output of the regulator, and this really limits the selection of components it seems. I've also looked through a lot of supercapacitor backup supply ICs, but none of them are suitable for the rather special input scenario I am facing. Also, they are typically designed as a back-up, and not as a power boost.

I hope someone have any suggestions on what I should look into (or rethink for that matter), as I am somewhat stuck. I also have to mention I am a DIY beginner in switching regulator design, and my lack of experience may of course be the reason why I am incapable of not finding the solution myself.

Comment: Are you sure you only need couple second to connect to the WiFi?

Comment: Pretty sure. But if I need more time, it's simply a matter of using a bigger cap (or 2). The issue is how to use the extra power in the cap at will.

Comment: Providing the desired worst case conditions would make it a lot easier to help you. We can guesstimate what >300 mA, up to 5V, Vmin on cap (maybe not defined by you), ... are BUT if YOU can set the desired hard limits its more designable. || Consider floating a battery at your target voltage. 3.9V is probably an acceptable continuous float voltage for a single LiIon cell. Most of the time it "just sits there".